# Using StatusBar Cordova plugin show() doesn't work when status bar initially hidden

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, statusbar

I am using the Cordova StatusBar plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar It works well except when I initially hide the status on iOS.

What I try to do:

- on iOS
- Hide status bar when splashscreen is visible
- Show status bar when splashscreen disappears

For that, I modify my plist as specified in the plugin's README. It works fine, the status bar is hidden when splashscreen is launched.

However, when I use `StatusBar.show()`, it **doesn't** work. The status bar stays hidden. (I use `StatusBar.show()` on `deviceready`event.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've finally resolved my problem.** I post here what I've found if anyone wants to achieve the same thing I did.

First note that I use **PhoneGap Build**, so this solution applies to that service.

To hide status bar during the time the splashscreen is visible, you need to modify the app's plist file (as stated here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#hiding-at-startup).

To achieve on that on PhoneGap Build, you have to add the follwing lines to your config.xml file:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden"><true/></gap:config-file>
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance"><false/></gap:config-file>
```

Then you'll need to voluntarily show the status bar. So when hiding the splashscreen, use StatusBar.show();.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    StatusBar.show(); // Status bar is initially hidden, we need to show it when splashscreen disappears
}, 2000);
```